# How to fix build after update to Java11

Tags: eclipse, scons

I do use scons 2.5.0 (update will come soon hopefully) and I switched from `OpenJDK 1.8` to `jdk-11.0.2` and I also changed Eclipse version used for build to `eclipse-rcp-2023-03-R-win32-x86_64`.

In `..\project\_user\TESTEnv.ini` I refer now:

```
JAVAH=C:\LIBRARIES\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac.exe
ECLIPSE_PATH=F:\Installations\Other\eclipse-rcp-2023-03-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse
```

piece of my `../project/TESTWKS/TESTFw/TESTKernel.m/SConscript.3dn`

```
import tcscons
e['TC_MODULE'] = tcscons.module_name()
e['TC_JAVA_MODULE'] = 'com.tt.test.kernel.jni'

classes = e.Java(target='${VARIANT}/java/classes', source=['java/src'])

jar = e.Command(
    '#java/${TC_JAVA_MODULE}${JARSUFFIX}',
    [classes],
    [
        '${JAR} cf ${TARGET} -C '+e.Dir('${VARIANT}/java/classes').path+' . '
    ]
)

headers = e.JavaH(target='LocalGenerated/java/java', source=classes)

e.Alias(['jni'], [jar, classes, headers] )
e.Depends('jni', '3dn')
```

I face problem with `java.h` file. Scons does not create proper command for me, I get in console:

```
C:\LIBRARIES\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac.exe -d TESTWKS\TESTFw\TESTKernel.m\LocalGenerated\java\java -classpath TESTWKS\TESTFw\TESTKernel.m\release\java\classes -h com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTClass1 com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTClass2 com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTClass3 com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTKernel com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTClass4 com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTModelEntityIdType
error: Class names, 'com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTClass2,com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTImage
PixelFormat,com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTKernel,com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTClass4,com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTMode
lEntityIdType
,com.tt.TEST.kernel.jni.TESTVisuItem', are only 
accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error
scons: *** 
[TESTWKS\TESTFw\TESTKernel.m\LocalGenerated\java\java\com_tt_TEST_kernel_jni_TESTClass1.h] 
Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Seems like I do miss `.java` extension in class names. How to do this in clever way?

I need in console something like:

```
C:\LIBRARIES\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac.exe 
-d TESTNWKS\TESTFw\TESTKernel.m\LocalGenerated\java\java 
-classpath TESTWKS\TESTFw\TESTKernel.m\release\java\classes 
-h TESTWKS\TESTFw\TESTKernel.m\LocalGenerated\java\java TESTWKS\TESTFw\TESTKernel.m\java\src\TESTKernel.java
```

I know there is `JAVAHCOM` created in `/project/_build/scons/2.5.0/scons-local-2.5.0/SCons/Tool/javah.py`, but I do not want touch this.

Comment: I suggest you updated to the newest SCons and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell if this is your specific problem, but SCons, due to the various changes in certain Java details over time, carries a list of "known versions" of Java, and what to do with them, and rejects the rest. It's possible that 2.5.2 is so old it doesn't know about Java 11, and if the tool setup fails, then SCons simply won't have entered the Java suffixes into the table mapping suffixes to builders. I *believe* Java 11 was added to the compat table in SCons 3.1, but it would take some digging to be completely sure.